# iOS Clips app: What is the difference between Save Video and Save to files on iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, clips.app

When using Clips app on iO S12, I see two options Save Video and Save to Files. What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 1):

"Save Videos" saves the video to the Photos image & video library.

"Save to files" means to save the video as a file to for example iCloud Drive, Dropbox, OneDrive, local storage or other storage service!

Comment: So wheres video in `Photo image & video library` live? Isn't it already in local storage?

Comment: Open the Photos app, and you’ll see it in there! The actual storage location is often on device, but might also be in the iCloud Photos Library.